# How to change FontAwesome's glyph color inside JFXButton through hover selector in CSS?

Tags: css, hover, javafx-8, font-awesome

I have a toolbar (VBox) with several JFXButtons. All button's caption and glyphs are white. I want to change only glyph color when mousepointer is over the button.

The CSS file:

```
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-fill: white;
}

.button .glyph-icon:hover {
    -fx-background-color: derive(black, 15%);
    -fx-fill: #cc8f1e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the 'color' property for glyph

Answer (score 0):

Define the *hover* state of the button first, then another *hover* state with the glyph-icon, like this:

```
 .button
 { 
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-fill: white;
 } 


.button:hover
{
-fx-background-color: derive(black, 15%);
-fx-fill: #cc8f1e;
}


.button:hover .glyph-icon, .button:hover .glyph-icon
{
-fx-text-fill: #cc8f1e;
}
```